# Weird ethernet behavior in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

## Problem description

As you can [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvVcE.png), the internet connection is not stable in my Desktop. The weird thing is that this problem is not present in windows OS (in the same machine). Neither is it present on any other device in my house. The connection essentially halts every 10 seconds under a heavy download (from any mirror). After 4 ou 5 seconds, the download continues. This repeats until the download is finished. The motherboard is an Asus Strix X470-F gaming (Intel NIC).

## What I already tried

- **Change internet adapter**: Bought a cheat realtek ethernet PCIe add-in card and the problem is still present.
- **Different Linux distros**: Tried arch (latest), fedora (latest) and ubuntu server 16.04 and 18.04. I tried with both the onboard and the add-in card. The problem is still present.
- **Change cables**: Same outcome.
- **Connect to the switch instead of connecting directly to the Router**: Same outcome.
- **Mess with the BIOS option**: I tried to mess with a few options in the BIOS... Can't remeber them all or what they did
- **Force negotiation to 100mbps instead of 1000mbps**: Problem is still present.
- **Bridge the connection with my laptop**: Another thing I tried was to connect my laptop (windows) via wi-fi (to the router) and bridge the wi-fi adapter with the ethernet adapter. Then I connected my desktop to the laptop (vie ethernet). Here the problem is NOT present. I have a stable connection.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dj2O.jpg) is a screenshot of Wireshark in the moment the connection stalls.

What can I do next?

Comment: Have you tested a _local_ transfer, between two devices on your LAN (such as iperf3)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did a test with iperf3 between a laptop (connected via wi-fi) and my desktop (LAN). I got 444Mbps (limited by Wi-fi probably) stable. So the problem does not appear in those conditions.