# Weird ISP setup: Static ip behind carrier-grade NAT

Tags: networking, ip, nat, isp, tomato

I'm new to "ISP level" networking so this question might be a bit naive.
I've been having [weird network issues in linux machines](https://superuser.com/questions/1530988/weird-ethernet-behavior-in-linux). As a debug/learning initiative, I decided to try and replace my ISP router with one of mine (connecting it directly to the ONT). I asked my ISP for help and they gave me this information:

- `VLAN`: 12
- `Remote IP`: 100.64.xx.xx
- `Local IP`: 100.64.xx.xx (+1)
- `Internet IP`: 62.xx.xx.xx

After a bit of research, it seems my ISP is using a carrier grade nat setup. The weird thing is that I also pay for a static ip (the one that start with 62...) and it works fine (I have a few clients that connect to my server via a VPN, using this static IP).

To my understanding, this makes no sense since a carrier grade solution should not be compatible with a static external IP, right?

I already tried setting the WAN port in the correct VLAN and with the Local IP and Remote IP as gateway, but I still can't access the internet. I also tried to connect my PC directly to the ONT and use wireshark to see the packets that arrive. Some packets arrive with my external IP address (62.xx.xx.xx) so it's obvious it has to be in the router configuration somewhere. I just don't know where.

Can someone explain this to me? Ideally, some help regarding setup of a router running tomato (or open-wrt) would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my understanding, this makes no sense since a carrier grade solution should not be compatible with a static external IP, right?

No, not necessarily. There's a bit more to IP routing than "there's a NAT / there isn't a NAT" and it's not always based on what the IP address looks like.

There are at least two "normal" ways for doing this. (I think your ISP is using the first method, since it's more conventional and you've said that you are actually receiving packets which still show the public IP address as destination.)

#### 1. Routing

The first way is for the ISP to route any additional addresses via your router's "primary" address. This is actually the normal way corporate networks receive address ranges: they *do not* directly assign hundreds of addresses to the router itself, but only route the whole range *through* it.

For example, in Linux iproute2 terms, the ISP's system just has something like this:

```
ip route add 62.x.x.x/32 via 100.64.x.xplus1
             ^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
your additional IP |                | your router's primary IP ("local")
```

This gives the router great freedom to decide where to send packets further. You *can* assign the address to the router itself, or you can add a similar route that forwards to your home server – allowing the server's `eth0` to directly have that address.

In this process, your packets **do not go through CGNAT at all.** The route nexthop's only purpose is to be translated to a layer-2 address – it never shows up on actual packets. Therefore it doesn't matter if your router's "primary" address is from a private range or not, as it only needs to be known by the ISP's internal routers.

(In fact, even sites which don't have any form of CGNAT will occassionally assign private-range IP addresses to their routers, just as a means to conserve their public address space.)

#### 2. Static NAT

They can also achieve this by defining a separate 1:1 NAT rule just for you, so that *all* inbound packets for 62.xx.xx.xx get DNATed to your 100.64 address, and vice versa – all packets sent from you get SNATed to your reserved external IP.

(It works just like the "DMZ" setting in home routers, and in fact it's very much like the "Floating IP" system in Amazon AWS and similar cloud megaproviders.)

If the ISP's infrastructure is already configured to put everyone behind NAT, it's possible that this approach is much simpler to configure on their side than actually routing the public address to your device (fewer moving parts needed).

However, if this were the method used, then you would never *see* packets arriving with the external IP address as destination: they would *all* be NATed to your CGNAT private IP address.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @user1686 :) So, if I understand this correctly, I have to add a routing rule to my router but I don't seem to understand what the rule is. It's as if I want a combination of NAT and routing. I need packets that arrive at my router in its WAN interface with dst=62.xxx to be "NATed" to my local home IP range (192.168.1.0/24). I'm not sure how to achieve that. I tried a routing rule, routing external packets to 192.168.1.1. Did not work. Can you give me some more guidance? Thank you again

Comment: Routing is always performed, even with NAT, but the way you stated the requirement doesn't really make sense. Are you talking about incoming connections or outgoing connections?

Comment: Generally, just configure the router as you always do, then add the extra address to the same WAN interface, then create a NAT rule in your firewall (on Linux use DNAT instead of MASQUERADE).

Comment: After getting a new pfsense router a managed to do what you said. Everything is working now. Thank you for your help